# Change language of PrimeFaces "Editable Schedule" component

Tags: primefaces

I want to change language of days, months, hours that are inside of ["Editable Schedule"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv3sw.jpg).

How to do that?

Comment: Follow this link on GitHub: [Primefaces locales](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Locales)

Comment: what language do you want to translate to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a JavaScript-File with the translation in your Project and include it.

Example German I called it de.js

```
PrimeFaces.locales['de'] = {
    closeText: 'Schließen',
    prevText: 'Zurück',
    nextText: 'Weiter',
    monthNames: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mär', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
    dayNames: ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'],
    dayNamesShort: ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi ', 'Do', 'Fr ', 'Sa'],
    dayNamesMin: ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi ', 'Do', 'Fr ', 'Sa'],
    weekHeader: 'Woche',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    timeOnlyTitle: 'Nur Zeit',
    timeText: 'Zeit',
    hourText: 'Stunde',
    minuteText: 'Minute',
    secondText: 'Sekunde',
    currentText: 'Heute',
    ampm: false,
    month: 'Monat',
    week: 'Woche',
    day: 'Tag',
    allDayText: 'Ganzer Tag'
};
```

Include

```
<h:outputScript name="yourPath/de.js" />
```

After that use the local parameter of `<p:schedule>` and set the local as you called it in your JavaScript `PrimeFaces.locales['de']`

```
<p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{myController.eventModel}" axisFormat="HH" columnFormat="ddd" timeFormat="HH:mm" 
            scrollTime="08:00:00" leftHeaderTemplate="today, prev, next" clientTimeZone="local"
            showWeekNumbers="true" view="month" draggable="false" resizable="false"  locale="de" />
```